# Unable to find collection I want to print

Tags: mongodb, controller, find, mongo-java-driver, mongo-collection

Im trying to display the collection of a mongodb server but having difficulty in the MongoController class finding the collection in the FindIterable. I believe it may be a syntax error but I cannot understand what is wrong.

MongoController class

```
import com.mongoDB.MongoDAO;
import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;

public class MongoController {


    FindIterable<Document> mondgoDB = collection.find();


      for (Document d : users) {
        System.out.println(d.toJson());
      }

      mongoClient.close();

}

}
```

MongoDAO class

```
package com.mongoDB;

import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MongoDAO {

    String mongoDB = "storeHeadOfficeDB";
    String mongoCollection = "storeHeadOffice";


    public MongoDAO() throws Exception {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDB);
        MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection(mongoCollection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mondgoDB = dbname.collection.find()
```